# is there a way Include two file extensions when opening a file

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a folder of images that are compromised of .tif and .tiff

`Application.FollowHyperlink "G:\Images" & ([Image_Name] & ".tiff")`

The code opens the image based on the image name the user currently has active. Which works but doesn't take account that the file could be either .tif or .tiff

How would I do that.

Answer (score 3):

Use the `Dir()` function to find out which version of the file name is present in your target directory.  Then open that file.

```vb
Dim strNameFound As String
strNameFound = Dir("G:\Images\" & [Image_Name] & ".tif*")
Application.FollowHyperlink "G:\Images\" & strNameFound
```

A [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65639548/is-there-a-way-include-two-file-extensions-when-opening-a-file/65639831?noredirect=1#comment116058949_65639831) pointed out that if both `[Image_Name] & ".tif"` and `[Image_Name] & ".tiff"` exist, this simple approach would open only the first name found and then stop.  If both file names exist, and you want to open both, you can adapt the code to call `Dir()` and `FollowHyperlink` again.

```vb
Dim strNameFound As String
strNameFound = Dir("G:\Images\" & [Image_Name] & ".tif*")
Do While Len(strNameFound) > 0
    Application.FollowHyperlink "G:\Images\" & strNameFound
    strNameFound = Dir
Loop
```

Comment: What if there are two files, one .tif and one .tiff? It will open the first one found and if that is ok with TS then fine. Otherwise there should be code to alert when both files exist.

Comment: @StureS Daniel told us in their question *"the file could be either .tif or .tiff"* I interpreted that to mean one or the other, but not both.  If both versions can exist and Daniel wants to open both, the updated answer will cope.

Comment: @HansUp yes, you are correct but TS might have overlooked the possibility which I pointed out. That's all.